# Post a tweet [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, post, twitter, xamarin

I am using Xamarin.Auth to authenticate with Twitter. I use code below to authorize:

```
private void LoginTwitter() {
    var auth = new OAuth1Authenticator(
        consumerKey: "KEY",
        consumerSecret: "SECRET",
        requestTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"),  
        authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),  
        accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"),  
        callbackUrl: new Uri("http://mobile.twitter.com")  
    );

    auth.Completed += twitter_auth_Completed;
    StartActivity(auth.GetUI(this));
}

private void twitter_auth_Completed(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs eventArgs) {
    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Logged in!", ToastLength.Long).Show();    
    }
}
```

Authorize is working but I want now to post a tweet on twitter.

What is the best way to do this after authorize?

Thanks.

Comment: Xamarin.Auth is just a library for Authentication (aka verifying a person as an existing user on twitter/...). For actual posting, you have to use twitters own api.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with iOS, use Social Framework: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_the_social_framework/

For Android, iOS, or cross platform, you can use something like LinqToTwitter (https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter/wiki). Here is a walkthrough with Android: http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2013/11/14/linq-to-twitter-runs-xamarin.android.aspx

There's a community video here that describes some of the options: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6w_OwswzZb4

Comment: Ah, just noticed that you specified Android :). LinqToTwitter is my recommendation, leaving the other links up in case you ever decide to go cross-platform.